# The selector " did not match any elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I’m using `Angular 8` with `ASP.NET Core 2.2`.
I have two pages  `Index.cshtml`  and Job  `newlist.cshtml`
In page `index.cshtml` I use tag  `<app-job-newlist></app-job-newlist>`.
Then in page  `newlist.cshtml` I use tag  `<app-jobpicload></app-jobpicload>`

When loading page `newlist.cshtml`, I see error:

> ERROR Error: `"The selector "app-job-newlist" did not match any elements"`

this my code `app-modules.ts`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
//import { CommnetComponent } from './commnet/commnet.component';
import { CommentComponent } from './comment/comment.component';
import { JobListComponent } from './job-list/job-list.component';
import { JobServiceService } from './services/job-service.service';
import { JobLoadFileComponent } from './job-load-file/job-load-file.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CommentComponent,
    JobListComponent,
    JobLoadFileComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [JobServiceService],
  bootstrap: [ JobListComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Well, where is `app-job-newlist` defined? Typically one names files after the components contained within them, so you should have a `job-newlist.component` file somewhere...

Comment: is it "app-job-newlist" or "app-job-list"? You component file name looks like "JobListComponent". Any stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Explain:

> Every component you want to use in your angular app have to explicit
>   import in correct module or else you will see that error because
>   angular cant find selector tag for that component

Fix

Make sure to import your `app-job-newlist` to your module

Comment: app-job-newlist  add module and page index.cshtml but other page only add <app-jobpicload></app-jobpicload> when redirect to newlist.cshtml add tag <app-jobpicload></app-jobpicload> dont tag  app-job-newlist

Comment: I really dont understand what you are trying to say